# MkDocs documentation not accessing theme.css file on nginx server

Tags: html, nginx, podman, mkdocs

I am trying to host my MkDocs documentation on an nginx server running inside a podman container.
The container and nginx are running correctly and I can access the site and all the html files are there and readable. Just not in the correct format (When I try it with `mkdocs serve` it all works properly).
It's just a [plain html site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBcGQ.jpg) without any of MkDocs graphics / UI.

This is the Containerfile / Image I have running on the container

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

#Copying MkDocs files
COPY /Kubernetes/site /usr/share/mkdocs-site

#Installing nginx
RUN apt update && \
    apt -y install nginx && \

#Switching out the default nginx.conf file for the correct one
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY /nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx

EXPOSE 8080

#restarting nginx so the .conf file is reloaded
RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx-log
RUN touch /usr/share/nginx-log/nginx.log
CMD service nginx restart && tail -F /usr/share/nginx-log/nginx.log
```

(I know that there are multiple things that could be dene differently, but they shouldn't affect the nginx site?)

This is my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events
{
   worker_connections 768;
   #multi_accept on;
}

http
{
   server
   {
      location /mkdocs-site/
      {
         autoindex on;
         root /usr/share;
      }
   }
}
```

(As the server is running correctly this also shouldn't be the problem)

And this is my mkdocs.yml

```
site_name: oss-k8s-documentation
site_url: ""

nav:
   - Change Management:
      - Custom Requirement: Custom_requirement.md
      ...
   - Misc:
      - Adding new Clusters to Rancher: adding_new_clusters_to_rancher.md
      ...
   - Images
      - Alerting Installation: alerting_installation_1.png

theme: readthedocs
```

(Not typing out the complete file here because I can't copy the code atm)

I also checked if the MkDocs build ran correctly and I couldn't find anny issues.
I followed the guides I could find and also tried to fix it myself, so if anyone can provide any help as to why the site isn't displayed in the correct format I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it. The Problem was with my nginx.conf. For the browser/nginx to correctly read the theme.css file you need to add `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` in the location block of your nginx.conf file